# Click on the dynamic element on table which is in the same row that element with known value

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have such table

```html
<table class="transaction">
<thead class="transaction">
<tr>
<th class="seqtitle" onclick="expandOrCollapse('seq2');">
<a name="seq2"> [Seq: 2]</a>   //dynamic id link
</th>
<th class="transtitle">
 "Some known text + some other dynamic id"  
<span class="toolbar">
  ....
```

And the challenge for me is to click on the link with dynamic id (in this case seq2) when I know  that in the same row there is an element with partially known value ("Some known text + some other dynamic id") 
I tried xpath with following-sibling and preceding-sibling but without success cuz I dont know how to reach dynamically generated link with id 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the XPath you've tried and explain what's wrong with that XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preceding-sibling` axis could've worked, for example :

```
//table/thead/tr/th[starts-with(., 'Some known text')]/preceding-sibling::th[1]/a
```

**brief explanation :**

- `th[starts-with(., 'Some known text')]` : find `th` element having text content starts with `"Some known text"`
- `/preceding-sibling::th[1]` : from such `th` elements, find nearest preceding sibling `th` element
- `/a` : from each of the preceding siblings `th` mentioned before, return child element `a`